# Horizontal selector for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, selector

I am trying to implement a Horizontal selector for selecting notes for my notes app as indicated in the attached image on Xamarin Forms and don't know the way.

Please help!

I tried to do it using list view or layouts but its not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9178.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview

Comment: Don't post links to images. Insert them directly instead.